# Grab Window and analyze pixels with Qt

Tags: c++, qt

i want to to do scrennshots every 100ms and analyze the pixels. I already got this code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QtGrabber qt_grabber;
    qt_grabber.start();
    return app.exec();
}

QtGrabber::QtGrabber() : timer_(this) {

    screen_ = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
    timer_.setInterval(100);
    timer_.setSingleShot(false);
    timer_.connect(&timer_, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(createScreenshot()));
}

QtGrabber::~QtGrabber() {

}

void QtGrabber::start() {
    timer_.start();
}

void QtGrabber::stop() {
    timer_.stop();
}

void QtGrabber::createScreenshot() {
   int scale_faktor = 10;
   QPixmap original_pixmap;
   if(screen_) {
       original_pixmap = screen_->grabWindow(0);
    }

    int width  = original_pixmap.width()/scale_faktor;
    int height = original_pixmap.height()/scale_faktor;
    QPixmap scaled_pixmap = original_pixmap.scaled(width, height, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);

    QImage scaled_image = scaled_pixmap.toImage();

    //scaled_image.save("/home/wowa/test.png", "PNG");


    for (int y=0; y<scaled_image.height(); ++y) {
        for (int x=0; x<scaled_image.width(); ++x) {
            QColor color(scaled_image.pixel(x,y));
        }
    }
}
```

If i run this program my CPU is usually used about 4% which is too much for me. Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: 4% is *nothing*, and it's probably for the single core the application runs on, which means on a multi-core system the utilization is even lower. If it was *40* then yes I would understand it, but not for only 4. Can you please tell us what problems that core utilization causes you? *Why* do you want to lower it?

Comment: I want to lower it because i want to run that program on an raspberry pi. I usually wanted to do a screenshot every 10ms but then the cpu is used about 20%

Comment: Does the QT timer hard wait or use some other mechanism?

Comment: Then you should measure *on* the R-PI, but not only the numbers, you should measure how it objectively feels for you. With this program running, does it *feel* slow for you? Compared to when this program isn't running? And you also need to think about what else the target system will be doing, if the total CPU utilization doesn't top out (i.e. it doesn't reach 100%, or only very seldom reaches 100%), then is there really a need to try and optimize the code? Finally, does making your program more unmaintainable outweigh a few saved milliseconds?

Comment: Also, "grabbing" a screenshot depends *very* much on things like resolution, what resolution do you expect to run at? Going from 1080p to 720p will lower the number of pixels by more than half, for example.

Comment: The resolution will be 1080p

Answer (score 0):

A general approach is profiling.
In windows, u can use visual studio, and in linux , valgrind can help.

Comment: I know that this command: screen_->grabWindow(0); takes the most time!

Comment: If so, you can probably do nothing about that. it's a Qt function. you may use another library, or use multi-threading in multi-core CPUs.

Comment: Can anybody suggest me an faster library? I think multi-threading will not help me in this situation.